# More efficient method of updating observableList

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

Here's my setup:

I have a mySQL database with some data.

I have a makeshift server built where it downloads this data and turns it into an `ObservableList` and 
the client can make its own copy of this `ObservableList`, call it `localList`.

If I want to make a new entry, the requirements dictate that it must be done by sending the new entry to the SQL database,
the server downloads it, the client pulls this update,THEN the client sees the update. (This is done since multiple clients will be accessing this database).

Here's my problem:
Currently, the way I do it is when I make a new entry, the server clears its `observableList`, fills it again, and the client clears its `localList` and fills it again.

I do not have to worry about the server code (it will be replaced with a more sophisticated server), but I am wondering
if my `localList` (from ObservableList) comes with some method that can compare to another list and make changes accordingly.

Instead of doing

```
ObservableList<myType> locallist = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

....
localList.clear();
for (myType element : serverList) {
    localList.add(element);
}
```

Each time I make a new entry, is there a more efficient way? Some type of `update` method possibly?

Basically the question boils down to:

Is there a way of setting an `observableList<myType>` equal to another without fully clearing the list and then adding the elements one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
Bindings.bindContent(localList, serverList);
```

do what you need? ([Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindContent-java.util.List-javafx.collections.ObservableList-)). It would work if you keep the same list instance in `serverList`, and don't reassign the reference.

Comment: Ahh yes that might work!

The problem is I don't actually have the actual server to work with, so I have no idea if the reference is reassigned or not.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The reference is local to your client code.

Comment: Ah I'm off my game.

I see what you mean.

You're right this works perfectly.